# How to migrate my app to httpClient?

Tags: angular, httpclient

here I have method in my service.ts

```
getEmployees() {
    let _url: string = this.API_URL + '/organization/1/users';
    return this._http.get(_url)
        .map(res => res.json().data)
         .catch(this._errorHandler);
}
```

and call in my app.component.ts to generate a list of my users...

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._usermanagementservice.getEmployees().subscribe(employees => {
    this.employees = employees; 
    });

}
```

And it works, but I have to migrate to current version of angular and use HttpClient, I'm stuck, please help :(

Comment: Try! https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: lol what's wrong with google? https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-http/

Comment: is there a source code for this?

Comment: Are you also moving to the latest rxjs operators?

Answer (score 1):

This is what mine looks like, using `HttpClient` and the new "pipe-able" operators.

```
import { catchError, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

getMovies(): Observable<IMovie[]> {
    return this.http.get<IMovie[]>(this.moviesUrl).pipe(
        tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))),
        catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

The subscribe syntax does not change.